# Scrolling down on interval if the user is scrolled all the way down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

I have this problem,

I'm creating a chat, which updates every 2 secounds, via AJAX.

Now I want to scroll to the bottom, every time it loads, great that works.

Now problem is, if they scroll up to check old messages, it will scroll them down, annoying right? Now I tried coming up with a solution, which imo should work. But I'm stupid so. Can anyone help me?:

```
function loadChat() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/load_chat.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#chatbox').html(data);
            //console.log($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight - $('#chatbox').innerHeight());
            //console.log($('#chatbox').scrollTop());
            if($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight - $('#chatbox').innerHeight() + 50 < $('#chatbox').scrollTop()) {
                $("#chatbox").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight}, 200);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

This code makes it scroll down no matter what, but my if statement should stop that... right?

Comment: Thanks taxicala for the edit :) I'm not sure why it didnt indent the code :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest setting a flag as follows:

```
var atBottom = true;
$('#chatbox').on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
        atBottom = true;
    } else {
        atBottom = false;
    }
});

function loadChat() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/load_chat.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#chatbox').html(data);
            //console.log($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight - $('#chatbox').innerHeight());
            //console.log($('#chatbox').scrollTop());
            if(atBottom) {
                $("#chatbox").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight}, 200);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

That way when the user scrolls up, the flag gets falsy and when the user scrolls to the bottom, it gets truthy.

Comment: It works now after I moved my <script src> to bottom of my body tag

Comment: This script will cause client issues because you binding to the on scroll, if you want to avoid those issues you should be unbinding and rebinding the event with a set timeout